# Update two tables in MySQL using INNER JOIN and WHERE

Tags: mysql

I don't think this is possible but thought I would check if it is, and if not ask for the most efficient alternative.

**Objective:**
Update `table_1` and `table_2` using one query with an `Inner Join` and `WHERE`

Currently I have:

```
UPDATE table_1
    JOIN table_2 ON table_1.user_id= table_2.user_id
SET 
    table_1.value = 9,
    table_2.value_fan = 43
WHERE 
    table_1.user_id = 1 AND table_2.fan_id =1
```

This correctly updates `table_2` according to the `WHERE` condition, but all the entries are updated in `table_1` where `table_1.user_id = 1`... ignoring the condition `table_2.fan_id = 1`

---

EDIT 
Sorry, I should have been more clear, I had a typo above, which is now corrected... Below is also a link to SQLFiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58d7b/1

As I hope you can see Table_2_winnings is correctly updated with only one user, James, getting any winnings (as he has a city_id =1 and group_id =1). However all the users in table_1 in group_id = 1 are updated. Where I only want James to be updated...

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  Could you provide an example, ideally by way of a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: How are entries updated in table1 when only table2 column values are set?

Comment: Have updated to include link to SQLFiddle.. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ON table_1.city= table_2.city
```

is the only join filter in your query. Since city can come multiple times in both tables, inner join acts like some what a cross join. See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69970/3) . 
So for getting the required columns only added one more join filter

```
and table_1.user = table_2.user;
```

So your update query will be :

```
UPDATE table_1,table_2    
SET 
    table_1.table_1_winnings = 6,
    table_2.table_2_winnings = 43
WHERE 
    table_1.city = 1 AND table_2.city_id =1
and table_1.city= table_2.city
and table_1.user = table_2.user;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1f84/2)